# What is wrong with the build path for 'ionic cordova run ios' to work?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

When I run the command 'ionic cordova run ios' with my ionic app, it gives me this error every time:

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['cordova-build']" should have required 
property 'class'.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
```

I have looked all over and cannot figure out what it means or where I can find the error in the code. Any idea where to look? I believe all my dependencies are working and I have ionic 4 running.

Comment: try removing "es5BrowserSupport": true from angular.json

Comment: hmm, unfortunately this didn't change anything. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your package.json

Try to update this line :

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.801.0"

npm install
```